# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-viewpager

The scenario is like this: [How to use ViewPagers in Tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602787/how-to-use-viewpagers-in-tabs)

Now, when I click on an image, which is in the ViewPager inside a tab, a new activity is suppose to start. But, on debuggging I find out that there is a `NullPointerException` at `android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged` and the new activity is not even created.

I've even tried

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "In onPause");
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) this.getCurrentFocus();
    ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) tabHost.getParent();
    parentViewGroup.removeView(tabHost);
}
```

But I still face the same problem. Your help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I've tested the application on Samsung Galaxy ACE and it works fine. Dont know what is going wrong on Samsung Galaxy TAB.